# UItableviewcells with background image not filling the whole width of screen?

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview

Hi i am new for ios and in my app i have created one `UITableView` and i have set background image for `UITableViewcell` but image not filling the whole width of screen as like below screen. Why this problem is occuring?

I mean `UITableViewCell` left and right sides gap is coming images is not filling whole cell width.

please help me someone

### my code:-

```
#import "TableViewController.h"

@interface TableViewController ()
{
    UITableView * tableList;
    TableCell * Cell;
}

@end

@implementation TableViewController

- (void)viewDidLoad {
    [super viewDidLoad];

    tableList = [[UITableView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, [[UIScreen mainScreen]bounds].size.width, [[UIScreen mainScreen]bounds].size.height) style:UITableViewStylePlain];

    tableList.delegate = self;
    tableList.dataSource = self;
    tableList.separatorStyle = UITableViewCellSeparatorStyleNone;
    [self.view addSubview:tableList];
}

- (NSInteger)numberOfSectionsInTableView:(UITableView *)tableView {
    return 1;
}

- (NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section {
    return 10;
}

- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {

    static NSString *simpleTableIdentifier = @"MyCell";
    Cell = (TableCell *)[tableList dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:simpleTableIdentifier];
    if (Cell == nil)
    {
        NSArray *nib = [[NSBundle mainBundle] loadNibNamed:@"TableCell" owner:self options:nil];
        Cell = [nib objectAtIndex:0];
    }

    //UIImageView *imageBackground = [[UIImageView alloc] init];

    if (indexPath.row == 0) {
        Cell.backGroundImage.image =  [UIImage imageNamed:@"cell_top.png"];
    } else if (indexPath.row == 9) {
       Cell.backGroundImage.image = [UIImage imageNamed:@"cell_bottom.png"];
    } else {
       Cell.backGroundImage.image = [UIImage imageNamed:@"cell_middle.png"];
    }

    //imageBackground.contentMode = UIViewContentModeScaleToFill;
    //Cell.backgroundView = imageBackground;

    return Cell;
}
- (CGFloat)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView heightForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath{

    return 44.0;
}

-(void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView willDisplayCell:(UITableViewCell *)cell forRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath{

    if ([cell respondsToSelector:@selector(setSeparatorInset:)]) {
        [cell setSeparatorInset:UIEdgeInsetsZero];
    }
    if ([cell respondsToSelector:@selector(setPreservesSuperviewLayoutMargins:)]) {
        [cell setPreservesSuperviewLayoutMargins:NO];
    }
    if ([cell respondsToSelector:@selector(setLayoutMargins:)]) {
        [cell setLayoutMargins:UIEdgeInsetsZero];
    }
}

@end
```

[image]

Comment: You have custom UITableViewCell and load it from loadNibNamed:@"TableCell". While loading the cell from nib make this issue. why you overrode the willDisplayCell delegate fun?

Answer (score 1):

Try to set the layoutMargins property of the cells and the `UITableView` to `UIEdgeInsetsZero`.

```
- (void) viewDidLayoutSubviews {

    [super viewDidLayoutSubviews];

    tableList.layoutMargins = UIEdgeInsetsZero;
}

- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {

    [...]

    Cell.layoutMargins = UIEdgeInsetsZero;

    return Cell;
}
```

Also check for the `contentMode` of the `UIImageview`.

```
Cell.backGroundImage.contentMode = UIViewContentModeScaleAspectFill;
```

Answer (score 0):

try set contentInset on Left = 0

```
self.tableView.contentInset = UIEdgeInsetsMake(0, 0, 0, 0);
```

Comment: no no it's not working how it become answer to my question?

Answer (score 0):

Use **Debug View Hierarchy** to figure out UITableView, UITableViewCell or UIImage is not filling the whole width of screen

http://www.raywenderlich.com/98356/view-debugging-in-xcode-6

Answer (score 0):

Please check your "TableCell" in the storyboard. Did you select custom insets option for your custom cell?

Answer (score 0):

Rather than setting up your table view with code, you want to do this in a storyboard. Then you'll want to use auto layout to connect constraints from the table view to the view controller's view. There are lots of tutorials available to teach you how to do this. Learning this will make things much easier in the long run.

Change the name of your `tableList` property to `tableView`. That will make more sense to other developers (including yourself in the future), since that's what it is (a `UITableView` instance).

Your cell is named `Cell` with a capital C, but you don't want to name properties with capital letters. Also, it doesn't need to be a class property the way it's being used. Remove it from the `@interface` section.

[Coding Guidelines for Cocoa](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/CodingGuidelines/Articles/NamingIvarsAndTypes.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/20001284-BAJGIIJE)

Remove the `-numberOfSectionsInTableView:` method. The default is 1, so you don't need code to return the default value.

Instead of `-dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:`, use `-dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:forIndexPath:`. Then you won't need to follow it with a test to see if a cell was returned (it always will be). You'll need to register your nib with `-registerNib:forCellReuseIdentifier:`. Or better yet, just design it in the storyboard.

It appears that your custom table view cell has a `UIImageView` named `backGroundImage`. That should be added as a subview to the cell's `backgroundView` property (which you'll need to create - the view, not the property, which is already part of `UITableViewCell`). Set the image view's `autoresizingMask` so it will resize with the `backgroundView`:

```
- (void)awakeFromNib
{
    [super awakeFromNib];
    self.backgroundView = [[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:self.bounds];
     self.backGroundImage.autoresizingMask = UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleWidth | UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleHeight;
     self.backGroundImage.frame = self.backgroundView.bounds;
    [self.backgroundView addSubview:self.backGroundImage];
}
```

Remove the `-tableView:heightForRowAtIndexPath:` method. You only want to use this if you return different values. The default row height is 44.0, so you don't need to do anything else.